# android how to give width n height to an image programatically

Tags: android, imageview

In my activity i am creating a Imageview dynamically. Every time it fetch the image from server create an imageview and set that image.

All images size also not same , so i want to put all images in a particular size.
But its not working. Here is my code bellow,

```
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        imageView.setImageResource(mContent);
        imageView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

                    imageView.setMaxWidth(400);
        imageView.setMaxHeight(400);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this,

```
    imageview.getLayoutParams().height=100;
            imageview.getLayoutParams().width=100;
```

Comment: i want to put zoom out and zoom in .How can i do that?

Comment: well its complicated. You have to look for examples. I am sorry I have no idea in it.